# Extjs 6.2 nested rowwidgets doesn't resize properly

Tags: extjs, nested, grid

I am creating a grid which should be multilevel (3 levels). I have some troubles with the last level, the last grid doesn't resize properly, we cannot see the entire grid.

See the fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dk9

ExtJs classic 6.2

**UPDATED**
I found a hack to refresh the grid size by overriding the rowwidget plugin.
The updated fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dkq

The added lines (bottom) are:

```
// HACKS: force delayed refresh size the grid in case of nested rowwidget
Ext.defer(function() { me.grid.view.refreshSize(true) }, 100);
```

Comment: I modified the solution a bit: I did this in the grid's view's `expandbody` event and fixes it as well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide a `minHeight` for all widget which will make the grids visible properly. Check the updated [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dkj)

Comment: Not enough, if there is more rows, it doesn't work:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dkh

Comment: I have updated my fiddle link, so for the upper grid there is a `maxHeight` with a `scrollable` to keep the height in check

Comment: I dont want nested scrollbars, I just want it like the 2nd level. With only one scrollbar.

Comment: Either increase the height or `minHeight` of panel or provide `scrollable` as false to panel. Anyways, your main issue was about that the grid was not visible so now its visible with height. Similarly, you need to play with that height of child and parent to understand the behaviour.